# Wear OS Lock Screen On-Off transition

Tags: animation, transition, wear-os, lockscreen, sony-smartwatch

I'm not a "code friendly" person, my knowledge in programming is very minimum.
I'm using non/low-code software for designs and animation.

Currently I'm working on few watch faces for my fiancé Samsung Watch 5 and I would like to implement a new feature if it is possible which should light up her "heavy" moments/days.

I wonder if it is possible to place a animation or a sequence of svg/png as transition between screen stages, one animation before the screen is turning off and another one at awakening, including before/after Always-On stage?

Eg: She love her bunnies and I would like to animate a simple one as "Bye Bye" and "Greeting" when she manually turn it on/off from buttons and to avoid motion activation to prevent unnecessary battery usage.

With other words I want the watch to "interact" with her.
A valuable feature which all brands fail to implement it through their products, aiding Highly sensitive people (HSPs) with sensory-processing sensitivity.

If it is possible, there is any chance to import and edit the face watch pack from Watch Face Studio  into Android Studio and add the functions and files? or might work on her older TIZEN/Galaxy?

Or anyone knows if it can be done on any other device/os?
Google’s Wear OS (Android Wear), Apple’s Watch OS, FreeRTOS, Tizen OS, Fitbit OS, Garmin Watch OS, Zepp OS?

Thank you!